# Swift Error: Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'

Tags: ios, swift

```
let email = MUser.sharedInstance.getUserEmail()
let json = [
    "listIds": [""],
    "contacts": [{ "email" : "\(email)" }]
];
```

I'm getting the error `Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'` when running the code above. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the dictionary `email: email` where `{`, `}` are not recognised keywords You can define your json like this :

```
let json = [
    """
    "listIds": [""],
    "contacts": [ {"email" : "\(email)" }]
    """
];
```

or if you prefer to construct your dictionary in contacts with code, you could do something like below:

```
let json = [

    "listIds": [""],
    "contacts": [[ "email" : "\(email)" ]]
];
```

Comment: Will this give me the same thing as the payload here? https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/api_v3.html

Comment: can you help please?

Comment: @LouisaScheinost This works with any payload, its in your hands to choose how do you want to create your payload. Generally, when working with jsons, I highly suggest you to avoid creating strings or unstructured dictionaries and arrays, instead create DTO (Data Transfer Object) using Swift struct / class and serialize/deserialize payloads using your classes. It will help your code to be cleaner and type safe. Checkout this link : https://learnappmaking.com/codable-json-swift-how-to/